# Is there a way for perforce diff2 to avoid considering source code comments?

Tags: perforce

I'm using the P4Python API to do a diff.

```
p4.run_diff2(file_1, file_2, tagged=False)
#file_1 and file_2 are C/C++ source files
```

But the problem with above code is that it's considering the comments section in code as well. Can I avoid comments altogether when doing the diff this way through API ?

Comment: When you say comments, you mean code comments like // or /* ... */ in C/C++ ?
This will require some coding.

Comment: Yes exactly. C/C++ kind of comments.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using 'diff2', the Perforce server is computing the differences, and your control over that differencing engine is pretty much limited to what you can specify in the '-d' argument to 'diff2'.

Perhaps if you shared more information about what you're really trying to accomplish, people would have other suggestions for you.

For example, you could download both files to your workstation (using 'p4 sync', or 'p4 print'), and then run a differencing tool of your choice on your workstation, configuring your tool to perform the diffs in the desired fashion.